# JIRA how to create subtask

Tags: c#, soap, jira

I have a requirement of creating a issue then create sub-task via soap. I am using agile-velocity-plugin-0.2.12 . I found function type "jiraSoapService.getSubTaskIssueTypes , jiraSoapService.getSubTaskIssueTypesFor Project" etc, but not getting any way to create a sub-task.

Comment: Can you expand on your question?

Comment: I need create subtask for task in JIRA and I don't found any API for it.

Comment: You may want to try https://answers.atlassian.com. JIRA support is fairly active there.

Comment: For JIRA 4.4 and higher  used:
createIssueWithParent(java.lang.String token, RemoteIssue rIssue, java.lang.String parentIssueKey)

Comment: you can take a look here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701315/jira-on-sub-task-creation-inherit-custom-fields-from-parent